# Why do I still have Outlook contacts with Source=LinkedIn despite the add-in being defunct since a year?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

Until March 2010, LinkedIn allowed you to access your LinkedIn contacts via the Outlook Social Connector 2013 and I used this function until it was [deprecated last year](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/kb/3053944). So far so good.

But now I noticed that some of my contacts still have as their source "LinkedIn" as shown below:

[image]

When I click on the LinkedIn-link, nothing happened because the "URL" of the link is just "LinkedIn", nothing else.

It was my understanding that the source refers to the address book where that contact is actually stored, for example in my Outlook contacts:

[image]

But in the case of LinkedIn that makes no sense (there is no LinkedIn address book anymore).

Now, the main reason why that bothers me is because the contact image of the LinkedIn contact is not being displayed on the emails from that person and I suspect it might have something to do with this contact apparently being stuck in some kind of limbo between existing and not existing... ;-)

Comment: Same problem here. Tired of it seriously

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an answer in the sense of an explanation as to *why* this happens, but what resolved it for me was to recreate my Outlook profile. This will download all mail from the server once again, but it fixed the issue.